# two next functions in one Java file

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

I have a page with two buttons.
When I press on the first button, which is called "index," I go to the right page.
When I press on the second button, which is called "annonce," I go also to the same page, as if I had pressed "index."

Here is my code:

```
public class zzzzMarket extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Sign);  
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf");  
        tv.setTypeface(face);   
    };

    public void NextFunction(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, index.class);
         startActivity(i);
    };

    public void NextFunction1(View v) {
        Intent j = new Intent(this, annonce.class);
        startActivity(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, where do you register the functions to the buttons?

Comment: Hi THX but what du U mean by that. I´m a beginner in android.

Comment: He's asking how you link your buttons to the methods in the Java code - my guess is you do it in the main.xml layout, with onClick="NextFunction" on both buttons

Comment: Thanks any way I´ve solved it by UR help.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

To answer, we'd need to see the code within your `main` XML layout, specially the `onClick` on your buttons.

My guess is that they both say `onClick="NextFunction"`

What you want is `onClick="NextFunction"` for the button that goes to `index`, and `onClick="NextFunction1"` for the one that goes to `annonce` (that's how your methods are named - maybe you should have names that properly carry your intent, like `public void goToIndex(View view)` and `public void goToAnnonce(View view)`, that would be less error-prone).

**Note:** Please respect the Java naming standards for methods, they should *not* start with a capital letter. That would be `nextFunction` and `nextFunction1`. And classes, on the contrary, should start with a Cap. So `ZzzzMarket`, `Index` and `Annonce`.

Comment: Thanks...Yes I want to ((What you want is onClick="NextFunction" for the button that goes to index, and onClick="NextFunction1" for the one that goes to annonce.))

Comment: So change your main.xml layout to have that :)

Comment: YES Thank YOU.... ITs Solved.... I changed my main.xml by adding 1 to nextfunction to annonce.